# Number of proposals on faster-rcnn modes,using Google's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

How can i reduce the number of proposals of the faster-rcnn based models provided by the Google's Object Detection API. I mean, is there a variable in the configuration files, pointing to the number of proposals,that i can modifie in order to reduce the number of proposals?Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not possible.  Why do you want to reduce proposals?  Just filter proposals based on score.  For example, If select proposals with score > 0.7 then you can “reduce” (i.e filter) number of proposals to use.  In general, take bboxes with score > 0.5.

Comment: I want to make my model as fast as possible in order to test it in a mobile device with limited perforamnces. I only have one class.Can you suggest any trick for increasing the speed of my model? (trading off with accurasy of course).Thanks for your help.